# Сделал бота для ВК, работает все отлично, но когда спамишь он выдает ошибку

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\slawa\Desktop[11]Игровой бот ВК\newfilhhjye.py", line 479, in 
sms(id, "Нет такой команды!")
File "C:\Users\slawa\Desktop[11]Игровой бот ВК\newfilhhjye.py", line 29, in sms
vk.method('messages.send', {'event.user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0,"keyboard": keyboard.get_keyboard()})
File "C:\Users\slawa\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 689, in method
raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: you should specify peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id or user_ids param

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: def sms(id, text):
    vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0,"keyboard": keyboard.get_keyboard()})

Вроде тут все отлично, но я не понимаю. Скорее всего бот не успевает обработать запрос, что нужно сделать чтобы успевал?

Comment: Перехватите try ошибку и при ее возникновении запишите куда нибудь все параметры которые вы в этот момент передавали в метод. Тогда возможно удастся понять какой из параметров оказался кривым и копать дальше, выясняя как он оказался кривым

Comment: vk.method('messages.send', {'event.user_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id': 0,"keyboard": keyboard.get_keyboard()}) что еще за 'event.user_id' такой заключен в кавычки? А вк говорит вам что один из этих параметров peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id, user_ids должен быть передан в запросе